# Homestead error on vagrant up "could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock"

Tags: laravel, homestead

I experienced this issue today. I try to rebuild my homestead from scratch because my Homestead suddenly become inaccessible.

I provision with `mariadb: true`.

Here is the error:

[image: Error]

Without `mariadb: true` everything provision perfectly.

Any solution for this?